# Set default_socket_timeout to infinity?

Tags: php, nginx

I know that in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` there is a setting called `default_socket_timeout` which in practice terminates connections that have not had a response pushed to them for a specific amount of time. 
I'm running a RabbitMQ-based AJAX "listener", which opens a connection and waits until it receives a response, if at all, then restarts itself.

The problem is that it may not receive a response for a long time - sometimes even up to 2 hours. When that happens the listener dies because it received `504 Gateway Timeout`. I know the average load - it's an in-house system, only accessible to a certain office - so too many sockets won't be a problem.
Is there any way to set `default_socket_timeout` to "no limits"? I tried `default_socket_timeout=0`, but that just reverts it to the default of 60 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried `-1`? If that doesn't work you could also set it to `(1<<31)-1` (2147483647) for a timeout of about 68 years. Btw, I read here at [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) that the `default_socket_timeout` only applies to establishing connections; for read/write timeouts it suggests to use [stream_set_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php)

Comment: @Kenney Thanks, I discovered that this setting is not relevant to my issue at all, see my answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah you got it resolved, great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that my `Gateway Timeout` issue was not related to `default_socket_timeout` at all. I ended up putting `fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;` in my nginx PHP location block and it solved the issue. Here's how my config ended up:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
}
```

This lets me have a long-running request that doesn't get cut off after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

For the sake of completeness:

```
default_socket_timeout=-1
```

disables the timeout....